# Prevent the assigned success handler depending on the content of the loaded file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, handler

I'm trying to find a way to prevent my normal success handler if some statement is true, e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...
    success: function( response ) {
        if ( response.success ) {
            // do success
        } else {
            // do fail, maybe login timeout
        }
    }
});
```

This is the easy way. Very simple just having an Object with `success = true/false`.

But is there a way to prevent my success handler being fired if a statement is true, e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...
    success: function( response ) {
        // do success
    }
});
$.ajaxFireBeforeAllOtherSuccessHandler(function(response) {
    return response.success;
});
```

and then this having `$.ajaxFireBeforeAllOtherSuccessHandler` (pseudo name) to trigger before all other success handler and determinate if the others will fire.

I know I can set the `statusCode` of the request maybe by `401` and then have a master control using `$.ajaxSetup`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
        401: function() {
            // this do fail
        }
    }
});
```

But it's not possible for me at the moment!

Another was is to have a check method where you wrap your callback in:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...
    success: function() { checkAjax(arguments, function() {
        // do success
    }); }
});
function checkAjax( a, c ) {
    return a[0].success && c.apply($, a);
}
```

**Is there a way to prevent the assigned success handler depending on the content of the loaded file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [jQuery.ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/#Prefilters)

Witch allows you to capture all ajax calls before the original success handler is fired. Then you can overwrite the handler and make test to see if you want to fire the original:

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function( opts ) {
    var _success = opts.success; // Copy original
    opts.success = function( r ) { // Overwrite original

        var args = [].slice.call(arguments), // Convert arguments to a native array 
            isTrue = !(r.success === false); // Do my testing here

        if ( isTrue ) {
            _success.apply( this, args ); // Fire original with the right context and arguments
        } else {
            // Do my alert thing in here
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks for your help [@jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9889811/887539)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a global way to decide whether to call the normal success handler, then I think you could do something like this:

Set up a global ajaxSuccess handler [as described here](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/).  Then, create your own property on the ajax settings object called something like `mySuccess: fn` and put your success handler there instead of the normal `success: fn` so that jQuery won't call it for you automatically.  Then, in the ajaxSuccess handler, you can interrogate the xhr object and decide whether you want to continue to call your success function.  If you do, then you can looking in the settings object to get the `mySuccess` handler and call it.

In a little less complicated method, you could just define a utility function that you would set for the normal success handler.  In that success handler, you would check the value of the response and if it was what you were looking for, then you could call the `mySuccess` function on the settings object.